# Laravel 5.2 set Http response status code to 403 on abort

Tags: api, laravel-5, response, http-status-code-403, abort

I write RESTful API and I want to use function `abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');` on every place in my code where this is needed, but response generated by `abort` has always status code 200! (I really want tho have status=403). How to do it?

Comment: Try using `return response($content = 'Unauthorized Action', $status = 403, $headers = array())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wanting to be returning a `response()` if you want to customise what is sent back.

Something like the below should do the trick:

`return response('Unauthorized action.', 403);`

And you would place this where you currently have:

`abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');`

Comment: No - this is not the same - if i place 'return' somewhere inside my nested function, I must pass result to caller (function) and that calling function must return it again. In the other hand - abort works like 'throw exception' so I don't need return anything. And this is what I looking for.

Comment: I don't know what I change, but it starts working! (?) I start inwestigaton by using `abort(403,'test')` directly in `routes.php` and after testing... it starts work...